# site_url in wp_options table mismatch with site URL in settings > general

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I'm working with a client on a Wordpress instance that resides at `subdomain.maindomain.com`. They would like it to appear as `www.maindomain.com/subdomain`.

Prior to my tenure they spun everything up with a reverse proxy and have the site appearing at `www.maindomain.com/subdomain` successfully... EXCEPT when you attempt to navigate within the WordPress admin dashboard.

For instance, clicking on the arrow for next page to navigate within the posts produces the following link (resulting in an error):

`https://subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&paged=2`

where it should produce:

`https://www.maindomain.com/subdomain/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&paged=2`

This happens throughout the admin dashboard (creating a new user, etc.), despite the permalinks for the public facing pages being generated correctly.

**What's setup correctly:**

`wp_home` and `wp_siteurl` in `wp_config.php` are both set to `www.maindomain.com/subdomain`

Site and home URL are also both set to `www.maindomain.com/subdomain` in Settings >> General in the WordPress admin dashboard.

**Possible issue?**

I did notice in the `wp_options` table that the site and home URLs are both set to `subdomain.maindomain.com`. Could that be the root of the issue?

I can also provide the htaccess base rewrite rules here if that's helpful.

*Beyond resolving this troublesome issue, I'm also generally curious if there are any instances in which a mismatch between the site/home URLs in Settings >> General and the wp_options table would actually be a good thing? It seems like this mismatch would always be bad.*

Comment: after you changed the urls, did you regenerate your permalinks?

Comment: Yup. Permalinks have been regenerated after changing URLs in wp_config and via Settings >> General. 

I haven't touched the URLs in wp_options table because I'm not sure if this mismatch is purposeful because of their strange setup?

Comment: This is where I first got the idea to look at `wp_options` — but I'm not totally sure it's an applicable solution here. 

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121084/login-to-wp-admin-redirect-to-points-to-wrong-url-after-migration